# CakePHP 2.2.2 not working on Windows IIS7

Tags: cakephp, iis, iis-7, url-rewriting, cakephp-2.2

I am trying to make CakePHP work over windows with IIS7 and i can not get it following the official documentation: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html#url-rewrites-on-iis7-windows-hosts

I have downloaded the rewrite module for IIS7 from here: 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7435
And then installed it as admin.

I created the **web.config** file inside my cakephp main folder as said on the documentation.

The result I'm having is that when i try to load my cakephp main folder with the browser, it tries to load the wellcome.png image of IIS7 (failing to load it) and it doesn't load any project or cakephp content.

If i remove the **web.config** file from my mail folder, cakephp loads but it shows the the following error:

```
URL rewriting is not properly configured on your server.    
1) Help me configure it 
2) I don't / can't use URL rewriting
```

What am I doing wrong? Any idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i have it working now.

What i had to do, after downloading and installing the rewrite module for IIS7 ( http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7435 )

- Create a new Site in IIS pointing to the CakePHP project folder
- Import and Apply the .htaccess files using the URL Rewrite Module

  - APP\webroot\.htaccess
  - APP\.htaccess

That's it.
Hope this can help anyone :)

Comment: Is it possible to run 'cake' in Web Sites Azure context? How is it installed rewrite module for this IIS?

Comment: @enagra rewrite module is accessible directly from IIS after installing it. Then you can simple import Apache .htaccess files and it will get converted to IIS format for rewrite urls.