# Rewrite rules not working for CakePHP on IIS

Tags: php, cakephp, iis

I have been trying to get rewrite rules to work on IIS for CakePHP using the following web.config settings which is in the root folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="^$" ignoreCase="false" />
              <action type="Rewrite" url="app/webroot/" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
              <action type="Rewrite" url="app/webroot/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="^$" ignoreCase="false" />
              <action type="Rewrite" url="webroot/" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 4" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
              <action type="Rewrite" url="webroot/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 5" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
              <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

All the CSS, JS and other files work fine. As does loading in the home page, but other pages such as `/pages/about` just show a 404!

EDIT: Screenshot of setup in IIS:

[image]

What's the problem? Thanks

Comment: IIS 404 or CakePHP 404? Set debug to 2 in core.php if latter.

Comment: IIS 404 as in the blue screen with red text.

Comment: If you set IIS webroot to app/webroot directory, you can ditch rules 1-4 and narrow the scope of your problem.

Comment: From what I can grok, if the REQUEST_FILENAME lines are working, you may need the full relative path to index.php in that last line (ie. app/webroot/index.php) - unless you follow my advice above that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have much experience with IIS but, returning to this question, I'm noticing some glaring issues. IIS has imported all the three of CakePHP's .htaccess without any regard as to which directory they are contained in.

CakePHP comes with two additional .htaccess files so that users can easily throw an installation into Apache and, regardless of the URL they try, they should always (hopefully) be redirected to the *correct* .htaccess file and things should "just work" (TM):

```
Document root     Additional .htaccess file     Correct .htaccess file
/ --------------> /.htaccess -----------------> /app/webroot/.htaccess
/app/ ----------> /app/.htaccess -------------> /app/webroot/.htaccess
/app/webroot ---------------------------------> /app/webroot/.htaccess
```

The way IIS has imported these files, assuming your document root is set to `/`, rules 3-4 (from the second .htaccess file) are not needed. But more importantly, due to the catch-all regex `(.*)` in rule 2 (from the first .htaccess file), no rule beyond rule 2 will *ever* execute - meaning requests will never be passed to index.php.

Anyway, you are not using Apache, so you can't haphazardly throw CakePHP installations around expecting them to just work. The correct document root to use in production environments (for performance and security) on any web server (Apache, IIS, Nginx, etc) is the aptly named `/app/webroot` directory. This directory contains index.php, static files, and the correct .htaccess file.

After that, all you should need is rule 5 (from the correct .htaccess file). It basically reads: "match all requests and send them to index.php, unless there is a real file or directory we can serve":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <rule name="CakePHP" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
              <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: That fixes the routing issue for pages but now none of the CSS works. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Since the above rule passes all requests (that are not *real* files) to index.php, I'm guessing you are getting a CakePHP 404 now? If so you want to check the CSS file's URL, as IIS is not finding it in the webroot folder.

Comment: Yeah getting a Cake 404 now. It's saying it can't find the CssController for the error. The url for the file is correct e.g. `/css/default.css`. Not sure what the fix would be? I've posted a screenshot in my OP of the setup in IIS. Is anything wrong there perhaps?

Comment: It seems from the screenshot like your webroot is the whole `/` folder and not `/app/webroot`, but I may be incorrect. I'm at the extent of my knowledge here and don't have an IIS box I can test on, so I've done some more searching instead. I think [this question](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/12497904) may lead you to your answer, specifically "Imported Rule 0" that he links to.

Comment: Thanks that fixes the problem :) You should update your answer with the code that is used in that link so my acceptance of your answer makes sense for others who might come along.

Comment: Set the host to access the /app/webroot/ folder, and set this on the configurations for windows host and it will work as charm. Will load all the css, js and images from the all of the webroot folders

Answer (score 6):

IIS7 does not natively support .htaccess files. While there are add-ons that can add this support, you can also import htaccess rules into IIS to use CakePHP’s native rewrites. To do this, follow these steps:

1.Use Microsoft’s Web Platform Installer to install the URL Rewrite Module 2.0 or download it directly (32-bit / 64-bit).

2.Create a new file in your CakePHP root folder, called web.config.

3.Using Notepad or any XML-safe editor and copy the following code into your new web.config file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect static resources" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(ico|img|css|files|js)(.*)$" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="app/webroot/{R:1}{R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">

                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="^$" ignoreCase="false" />
              <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
              <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 4" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
              <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">

                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hello i m tring to deploy cakephp application on iis7 server. i set default controller and action. it is fine but after that all other page show only defalut contrler and actions's display page. even my default admin page is also show the route(/) page. my url is http://one-stoppoolpros.com/onestoppool/ can you please help me. rewrite module is installed. and i copied web.config form cakephp tutorial to document root.PLZ

Comment: Your URL says 404 file directory not found. Did you follow the above steps? cakephp works on .htaccess for its URL rewriting but as specified IIS doesn't support that instead you need to create web.config in your root of the application. Let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: thanks @Tarun this is because i remove some files form server. i wll update and ask you about this again.