# Azure and CakePHP 3 in subdirectory

Tags: php, azure, web-config, azure-web-app-service, cakephp-3.x

1. My first problem is that I cannot make CakePHP 3 work correctly in a subdirectory hosten in Azure (so I have to use web.config for the rewrite rules)
2. I want to configure my top level web.config in order to have other php files at root and also have some rewrite rules on them.

**My structure I am trying to achieve:**

-file1.php

-file2.php

-folder/file3.php

-index.php

-/dashboard/ directory that contains cakePHP 3

For example my domain is https://mydomain.azurewebsites.net

I need when I write https://mydomain.azurewebsites.net/dashboard to do anything related with the cakePHP. if I write https://mydomain.azurewebsites.net/dashboard/users/list I am navigating to the template view "list" in "Users" controller.
Anything else I write before the /dashboard I don't wont cakePHP to treat as a controller or similar.

**Current situation**

Write now if I go to https://mydomain.azurewebsites.net/dashboard/users/list the page is loaded correctly but because I am loading the resources in the files like:

```
<link href="/webroot/backend/pages.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

the recources are trying to load from  https://mydomain.azurewebsites.net/webroot/backend/pages.css but not
https://mydomain.azurewebsites.net/dashboard/webroot/backend/pages.css

**Solution I found that I don't consider good**

Having define

```
<?php 
use Cake\Routing\Router;
$path = Router::url('/', true); 
?>
```

and use $path in front of the resources declaration. That means I have to change all my project to include this $path.

**Any help** with the rewrite rules or anyone else who hosted cakePHP 3 in a subdirectory in Azure?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `web.config` file to your Azure website’s root directory, by default it is: `D:\home\site\wwwroot`. And add the rewrite configuration settings as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Rewrite to dashboard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^webroot/backend/(.*)$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="dashboard/webroot/backend/{R:1}"
                      appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Through this file, any resource request like:

```
https://mydomain.azurewebsites.net/webroot/backend/pages.css
```

will be redirected to:

```
https://mydomain.azurewebsites.net/dashboard/webroot/backend/pages.css
```

Comment: Thank you, that answers one part of the question. That can solve the problem with resources, but not the problem that cakePHP is in a subdirectory. Anything you write next to the domain is consider as a controller from cakePHP having trouble defining a different website at the root directory. I was looking for a complete solution with web.config configuration.

Comment: You may also need to put this [web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713780/rewrite-rules-not-working-for-cakephp-on-iis/18944001#18944001) to `/dashboard` directory.