# Cakephp pages redirect to 404 not found on windows server

Tags: php, windows, .htaccess, cakephp, windows-server-2003

I have uploaded cakephp files on windows server,

I got an error HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found for all below pages.

```
http://exoticvoyages.ntechinfo.com/index/index
http://exoticvoyages.ntechinfo.com/index/search
http://exoticvoyages.ntechinfo.com/index/getcountry
http://exoticvoyages.ntechinfo.com/countries/index
```

But, if i redirect all above pages to http://exoticvoyages.ntechinfo.com/ then its working fine.

Main .htaccess file is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

App .htaccess file is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /app/
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Webroot .htaccess file is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /app/webroot/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Can anyone give me solution?

Comment: what is the default route in route.php

Comment: Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'countries', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));

CakePlugin::routes();

require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';

Comment: http://exoticvoyages.ntechinfo.com/countries/index must work but you mentioned its not working at top of your question and other are wrong they must be like indexes not just index.

Comment: No, I created IndexController without using model like $uses = array();

Comment: I got solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497904/htaccess-and-cakephp-2-on-windows-iis7

Answer (score 0):

check for the `Rewritebase` .

[**take a look**](http://cookingwithcakephp.blogspot.in/2008/04/installing-cakephp-into-subdirectory.html), and also [**here**](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/vanremortele/2011/05/08/cakephp_rewrites_on_windows_server_net_framework_4_0_extensionless_urls_fix).

Hope this will solve it.

Answer (score -1):

.htaccess is not working on windows IIS, and so on cake php u can use this  http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/vanremortele/2011/05/08/cakephp_rewrites_on_windows_server_net_framework_4_0_extensionless_urls_fix